Sveltekit app hosted in Flask does not render
I want to run a Sveltekit app from Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='sveltekit_build')

I don't have  static files so i instead of
return send_from_directory('client/public', 'index.html')

I tried this instead
   return send_from_directory('build/_app', 'index.html')

but In a browser, http://127.0.0.1:5000/ returns markup  instead of the app itself:
%sveltekit.head% %sveltekit.body%

I assume you are using adapter-static. It seems to me that the associated files are not being loaded. Are there any error messages in the browser console? Did you assign an empty string to the static_url_path attribute when instantiating Flask?

Take a look at this example with this explanation.

The Svelte application is exported to the static folder using the adapter and served from there. To do this, the export path in svelte.config.js is adjusted and the prefix static for static files in the Flask application is removed.

I switched to a static build.
Problem : build folder holds 404.html instead of index.html    - I am looking why .

is the normal sequence , using  Dynamic route,  Get  404  server error when trying
return app.send_static_file('index.html') because it is missing.
so flask should    load 404.html   ?
===========================
Does this look right?
@app.route("/")
def index():
return app.send_static_file('index.html')
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
return render_template("404.html")

I'm surprised you can't create an index.html file.
You can use the 404.html file in Flask, but you don't have to.
The error handler looks correct, but you can loop through the error code. However, that requires you to serve 404.html from the template folder. If you want to send the static file from the static folder, you need app.send_static_file(...) or send_from_directory(app.static_folder, ...) instead of render_template(...).

Have you created ./src/route/+page.js and specified 404.html as fallback in the configuration?

hi Detlef
Thanks for you astute comments.
I am going to try this  package  related to svelte :   flask-svelte
